# Java -version gives a warning

Tags: java, path, cmd

When I type "java -version" from command prompt, I get the following warning :

```
    Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
```

My JDK is in the following directory :

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

And I have also given the path to bin as :

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
```

Then, what is the problem?

Comment: JDK1.8 but dll from JRE6? That could be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, you've installed a jdk or jre version 1.6 and then added the 1.8 (which I'm guessing is a ver early non final version). That's why your JDK 1.8 executable is looking for libraries in your JRE6 install. Try uninstalling all JDKs/JREs and reinstall only the one you want to use. And if that doesn't work, try installing one of the stable releases like 1.7 from here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the x64 version. Based on your paths you are using x86 version of java jdk. Your path is looking for the msvcr71.dll on your x64 location.

Another thing to check, look into your environment variables and check if there are other instances of the java path there. You should have JAVA_HOME as a variable and include it into your path like so:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Hmm.. didn't notice that you were using 1.8 jdk. My bad. Indeed, Thilo correct, you are using 1.8 jdk while your jre is 1.6.